# Android Webview - how to disable auto forwarding due to wifi connection site

Tags: android, webview, android-wifi, onactivityresult

I thank everybody upfront for your time.
I am writing a simple webview application. If device has no internet connection, it starts an ActivityforResult, goes to wifi manager and comes back, it also receives state changes via receiver. However, I realized recently, if i use wifi of coffee shop, after wifi connection, it redirects first page to company website.
In my webview, even though I call to load my url again after wifi connection. It still goes to that website instead of mine. Since my webview is not designed :) for this, i have issues. Are there any way to get around this? Perhaps calling a fake URL before loading good URL?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(SurveyActivity, "Returning Application!");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
                getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            myWebView.loadUrl(siteURL);
            Log.i(SurveyActivity, "Internet connection established!");
        }else {
            Log.i(SurveyActivity, "No internet connection!");
            //quitApp();
        }
    }
}
```

Have my permissions in manifest as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Does it happen, if instead of using WebView, you open URL in external browser with startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUrl)) ?

Comment: I will check again when i m back to coffee shop :) . However, I remember trying loading URL twice one after each other without cache and it didn't work.